# jQuery: How can I get around using an if statement to get rid of "undefined" errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, undefined

When using third-party plugins, I typically initialize them in my main `application.js` file.

Example:

```
$('.scroll').jScrollPane();
```

The problem is if a page loads that doesn't have the `scroll` class, then I get:

```
TypeError: Result of expression '$('.scroll').jScrollPane' [undefined] is not a function.
```

So to get around this, I wrap it in:

```
if ($(".scroll").length){
    $('.scroll').jScrollPane();
}
```

That remedies the problem but just seems like a hack.

Is there a "correct" way to solve this?

Comment: That error seems to say that the function `jScrollPane` doesn't exist, rather than the element doesn't exist. In general, 0-length arrays in jQuery don't cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting:

```
ScrollPane' [undefined] is not a function.
```

...it wouldn't be because the page doesn't have a `.scroll` element.

That sort of error occurs when the plugin (or jQuery itself) isn't loaded.

If you're reusing some code on several pages, some of which don't have that plugin, do this instead:

```
if ( $.fn.jScrollPane ){
    $('.scroll').jScrollPane();
}
```

Comment: It should be noted tho, this is a perfect solution if you dont know IF you'll be including this plugin on a particular page, however, if you are expecting it to be on the page, make sure its under your jQuery script tag, and make sure it's linked correctly. Otherwise, take a look at my example too.

Comment: @Oscar: Yeah, I'm assuming that's the issue. Sounds like you have more experience with this plugin.

Comment: It's such a messy, messy plugin. It's always been my belief to keep window chrome UI to the browsers ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [try/catch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp) blocks...

```
try
  {
    $('.scroll').jScrollPane();
  }
catch(err)
  {
  //Handle or ignore errors here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhh ... no; jQuery doesn't work like that. A call to `$("any selector")` will **always** give you back a ready-to-use (but empty) jQuery object.  I don't think that's really your problem. Can you describe more about what your page is doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.scroll').jScrollPane()){
    $('.scroll').jScrollPane();
}
```

this error is prob just because an addon failed loading

Comment: Unless this plugin is developed in a non-conventional manner, the code would always return a jQuery object to the `if()` (even if there are no `.scroll` elements). As such, it would always evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As a couple others have said, that error is the jScroll's error. If it's because an element doesnt exist jQuery will return an empty array.

Its because the plugin isn't loaded. jScroll is the plugin to change the scrollbars, correct? I've had numerous issues with it. I suggest wrapping it in a

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //Call it here
})
```

This fixed all the issues i had with it.